# How to bind data from DB to a treeview in silverlight?

Tags: silverlight-4.0, treeview

Suppose I have a table in DB like:

```
Tab(id, parentid);
```

by EF, I can get the data collection as a tree like IQueryable by wcf service. 
say the data like
id parentid

```
1, nul
2, 1  
3, 1
4, 2
5, 2
6, 4
7, 4
8, 4
9, 1
```

Then I want to bind this data to a treeview, how to implement it?

Answer (score 0):

This data will be ItemsSource for you TreeView control.
This article answers for you - [How to Display Hierarchical data](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd759035%28VS.95%29.aspx)